# How to reduce the title space of AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have overridden the `titleSpacing` in the constructor of AppBar. But no difference in the title space.

```
new AppBar(

backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
title: new Text("Flying Dutchman",
  style: new TextStyle(
    color: const Color(0xFF444444),
    fontSize: 30.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
  ),
),
titleSpacing: 0.00,
centerTitle: true,
elevation: 0.0,
)
```

[image]

I wish to reduce the top space of the app bar title.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`titleSpacing` is not about the actual appbar height and top padding.  It's the spacing on the horizontal axis.

`AppBar` is a prestylized component that follows [material](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) rules.

If you don't like these rules, don't use `AppBar` to begin with. And go create your own component ! :)

Here's an implementation example :

```
class MyAppbar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyAppbar({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        height: preferredSize.height,
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text(title),
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(40.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remi. It works fine. But I have to add TabBar in my screen. Thats why I am adding AppBar. I can not rewrite entire code to place my tab bar on this `MyAppBar`. Is there any other way to reduce size or can I add TabBar without AppBar?

Comment: `TabBar` is just a widget like any others. It doesn't need to be used with `Appbar`. You can very well add a `TabBar` to my example.

Comment: Thanks, Remi. Works fine. I have added TabBar to the `MyAppBar`.

Comment: So simple, but exactly what I needed!

Answer (score -1):

Just make transform as root of text view and provide x value in nagtive.

```
new AppBar(

  backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
  title:new Transform(
            transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(-20.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            child: new Text("Flying Dutchman",
            style: new TextStyle(
                   color: const Color(0xFF444444),
                   fontSize: 30.0,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                   ),
             ),
           ),
 titleSpacing: 0.00,
 centerTitle: true,
 elevation: 0.0,
)
```